# Ubuntu installation: no partition is displayed except /dev/sda

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I am on windows 10 (Upgraded from 7). Trying to install ubuntu but at the 3rd step it just shows /dev/sda. I actually have 4 drives and unallocated space. Live boot from USB drive shows the partitions perfectly. I heard about that 4 drives issue too but that question comes later, right? I can't even see my 4 drives in installation process. I checked that my windows 10 boots in legacy mode & ubuntu too (because media loading screen is a purple screen not black & white terminal-like one). I disabled fast boot. I also followed the instructions in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions) question. But it doesn't apply since `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`
says I have only MBR partition table present. So I am out of clues here on what to do now

Found Libparted Error while opening GParted:
1) Can't have overlapping partition
2) Can't have a primary partition inside an extended partition

[Screenshot of the 3rd step I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSXy1.png)

Screenshot of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda:

[image]

Comment: The system is showing you the disk select option where to install the boot loader. If you click the little arrow, just above the Install Now button, you should see your other disks.

Comment: no sorry. If I click the little arrow then there's only one option which is the one you see in the screenshot

Comment: You probably have four primary partitions already, all used by Windows. With MBR partitioning scheme you cant have more than four primary partitions. To be sure you should add the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` to your question. Copy the terminal output and paste it via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/915023/edit) to your question.

Comment: I was having trouble formatting the text. so just added the screenshot of it^

Comment: You have only one disk `/dev/sda` with about 30 Gb free space. That should do it. The question shown in your screenshot is about where to install the bootloader - this should be done in the MBR of `/dev/sda`, so what is the problem? It is not about where to install the OS!

Comment: There is a problem with `sda3` (11.5GB). This is a primary partition, but located in your extended partition `sda4`. I wonder how this is possible.

Comment: @ridgy In the `Something else`-section this is the step where we choose,create and change partitions, define the mount-points and so on.

Comment: @FarhanFuad Don't worry about formatting, we can do that, its better to have relevant information in the question than to use links. Also terminal output pasted as text is better to work with.

Comment: Mook765 has identified one problem. See if fixparts will let you convert sda3 to a logical partition so correctly inside extended. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/  Also with Windows 10 you have to make sure fast start up or hibernation is off. Windows will keep turning it on, so have a Windows repair disk so you can repair Windows. Grub only boots working Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: The four-primary-partitions limit is not the issue. My first thought is that this is a driver problem, which is causing hard disks to not be detected because the disk controller chipset is not being detected. Switching modes in the firmware (AHCI to IDE or vice-versa) might fix that problem, but Windows might then flake out. It could also be a damaged partition table, as described on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/) That would not explain the failure of entire disks to show up, though.

Comment: I will try your suggestions
and one more thing, I don't know if it's relevant. on windows disk management I had actually 6 partitions. but it only showed 4 always. What I discovered is that, there were 2 drives with no drive letter assigned to it: Hp Recovery and SYSTEM. So, I just assigned a letter and it showed up in "my computer." Screenshot in the question is taken before doing that. Just so you know

Comment: Also I have included two errors given by GParted. You might want to check